# How get Mono Xamarin Android app path folder?

Tags: c#, android, path, mono, xamarin

Mono (Xamarin) Android application path, how do get? I found one way, it look like better I found

```
string path = "";
System.Collections.IDictionary vars = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in vars)
{
     if (entry.Key.ToString().Contains("HOME"))
         path = entry.Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 16):

In your Android application you could use:

```
// Documents folder
string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
   System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

This will get you the path:

```
/data/data/YourAppName/files/
```

Comment: What should I do if my application was install in `sdcard0` directory?

Comment: Does the app need permissions to write there?

Comment: No, apps don't need permissions to write to their data directories, only to access other places (outside data or SD card)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you need. Give the local files root.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData
```

and when you need get a file's full name you can do something like this:

```
string _fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "filename.txt");
```