# Xamarin : System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path "/kms.pdf" is denied.'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How can I download a pdf file from the sqlite database to the phone, I use this codeز

```
var Iteml = e.CurrentSelection[0] as SamplesData;
            byte[] wpdf = (byte[])Iteml.PDF;
            string name = "kms.pdf";
         
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            fs.Write(wpdf, 0, wpdf.Length);
            fs.Close();
            File.OpenRead(name);
```

but I see this message

Xamarin : System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path "/kms.pdf" is denied.'

I want to retrieve pdf files from database saved in bytes on the phone

Comment: You can't write to root! You have to select your application space and write there, where the app is enabled to.

Comment: `/kms.pdf` is an absolute path. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29644335/150978 how to get the path of your app private directory.

Comment: @Marco how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can pust the file in the app's own folder. Such as:

```
string name =Path.Combine(Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath,"kms.pdf");
```

And the value of this is `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/your app packaged name/files/kms.pdf`.

And if you want to put it in the public folder such as the **Document folde**, you need to get the write the external storage permission for the android 12 and lower. On the android 13, the permission is removed.

You can refer to the official document about the [Granular media permissions in the android 13.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions)